# Laravel doesn't open a file with a specific name from the public folder

Tags: php, laravel, filenames, assets, homestead

### The problem

I use Homestead and I have an `images` folder under `public`, and there is a JPG called `about_us-employee_1_image.jpg`. If I try to open it under its proper URL: `http://project.local/images/about_us-employee_1_image.jpg` I get a `NotFoundHttpException`. This happens with only this particular image and only with this specific name. If I change *any* of its characters it suddenly works again.

### Failed solution attempts

The problem is not related to routing because I deleted all of my routes and it still happening. I ran `php composer.phar dump-autoload` with no success. File and folder permissions are OK (this couldn't be the problem anyway, cause renaming wouldn't solve it).

Is there some kind of rule for naming assets that I'm unaware of?

### Stack trace

> NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 8257:
>
> 1. in compiled.php line 8257
> 2. at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7496
> 3. at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7461
> 4. at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7453
> 5. at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2302
> 6. at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request))
> 7. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9585
> 8. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2926
> 9. at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
> 10. at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9577
> 11. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 12949
> 12. at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
> 13. at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9577
> 14. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 11536
> 15. at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
> 16. at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9577
> 17. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 12686
> 18. at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
> 19. at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9577
> 20. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 12623
> 21. at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
> 22. at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9577
> 23. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2983
> 24. at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
> 25. at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9577
> 26. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
> 27. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9567
> 28. at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 2249
> 29. at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2232
> 30. at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54

Comment: did you try `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: I don't know. This question is more than a year old. I moved from Homestead to Laradock.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Storage helper that laravel provide for u but you need to add the new disk in config/filesystem.php

```
'front' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

and use it like this

```
$example=Storage::disk('front')->get('about_us-employee_1_image.jpg')
```